# Stone–Čech compactification vs Stone Duality

Tags: general-topology, boolean-algebra, compactification

Let $B$ be a Boolean algebra. There are two ways to turn $B$ into a topological space.

1. View $B$ as a discrete space and take the Stone-Cech compactification resulting in $\beta(X)$. This is the same as the Stone space associated to the Boolean algebra $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of powersets of $X$.
2. Take the Stone space of $\mathcal{B}$, $\mathrm{Ult}(B)$.

What is the relationship between $\mathrm{Ult}(B)$ and $\beta(X)$?

Comment: Definition 1 doesn't use the Boolean algebra structure of $B$, so the answer is "not very much". Consider the fact that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ non-isomorphic countable Boolean algebras.

Comment: The Stone space of a Boolean algebra has as underlying set its set of ultrafilters, but it's not its powerset; indeed, it's a compact Hausdorff space, and as such it [coincides with its Stone-Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Čech_compactification#Examples).

Comment: @RobertFurber I have a follow-up question. Now let $B$ be a Boolean algebra of sets, so a subset of the powerset of some finite or infinite set $X$ such that $B$ forms a topological basis and let the space generated be $Y$. It seems more likely that there is a nice relationship between the Stone-Cech compactification of $Y$ and $Ult(B)$ since they both utilize the Boolean algebra structure. Do you have any guesses about this?

Comment: @T-Biconditional In your question, do you mind saying what $X$ is?  You have not specified it.

Answer (score 0):

The Stone space of a product of a family of Boolean algebras is homeomorphic to the Stone-Cech compactification of the union of the Stone spaces of the members of the family, see S. Koppelberg, Handbook of Boolean Algebras Vol 1,  Theorem 3.8.9.